# Kerberos issue in Mac

Tags: macos, kerberos, spnego

I'm facing issues with kerberos in mac os. everyone except me in my office is able to use kerberos and kerberos enabled web urls, but it's not working for me.

I've checked my krb5.conf, it's in line with everyone else's.

I'm able to generate ticket using terminal, and it's able to connect to the kdc. but when i try the same using Ticket Viewer, i'm not able to generate ticket.

I'm thinking if ticket viewer is unable to connect to KDC, maybe browsers (chrome, safari, firefox) are too struggling to get the ticket from my system (maybe?)

Can someone help me understand how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, installing anaconda also installed kinit module in conda env, which interferes with system level kinit configuration.

As conda base env is loaded by default (which caused the problem), just deactivating it and then doing a kinit resolved the problem.

```
conda deactivate
kinit <user>@<realm>
```

It also started showing up in Ticket Viewer